# How can I debug my while loop C++ program?

Tags: c++

Please disregard some of the undeclared variables. I do not really know what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int number{}, tries{}, ans{}, count{};

   cout << "Enter an integer greater than 0: ";
   cin >> number;

   while (number > 0){
        ans = number / 10;
        ++count;
        if (ans == 0){
            cout << "The number has " << count << "digits";
            break;
        }
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ```number``` is not changing any where inside the loop. so how can the loop end?

Comment: First welcome to Stackoverflow. Second the way you titled your question is very vague. And your question is not clear.  Please give more information on your next questions and be more clear. Please note code that you leave here should be more complete. Please read more information about how to ask questions.

Comment: Even though you do not know what is wrong with the code, you probably know what is wrong with the functionality (or else you probably wouldn't be asking this). So what is wrong with the functionality? What happened (actual result) and what did you want to happen (expected result)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually changing `number`, so every iteration, you set `ans` to the same thing and run the same test.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, you are not updating the loop variable (number) anywhere inside the loop. Hence it is very likely to get in an infinite loop. Here is a sample updated code you can try out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number{}, tries{}, ans{}, count{};

    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 0: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number<=0){
        cout << "Incorrect input.";
    }
    else{
        while (number>0){
            number = number / 10;
            count ++;
        }
        cout << "The number has " << count << " digits";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Will definitely try this out.